# Error adding gesture to visual gesture builder frame source with kinect v2

Tags: c#, kinect, gesture, kinect-sdk

After creating gesture database using Visual Gesture Builder, I'm trying to write my own project to detect gestures.
After see the example of "DiscreteGestureBasics-WPF" that comes with SDK Browser, I tried to write my own code, but when I'm trying to add gesture to the "visual gesture builder frame source" object, I'm getting an exception:

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder.dll"

I already added in the post-build event the line `"xcopy "$(KINECTSDK20_DIR)Redist\VGB\x64\vgbtechs" "$(TargetDir)\vgbtechs" /S /R /Y /I"`
but it still not working.

If I'm using the example that comes with the kinect sdk, everything working fine, but when I'm trying to write my own project it isn't working at all.
I test my custom database on their project and it's working.

this is the line were the code isn't working:

```
     foreach (Gesture gesture in database.AvailableGestures)
     {
         if (gesture.Name.Equals(this.hands) || gesture.Name.Equals(this.handsUp))
            {
                    this.vgbFrameSource.AddGesture(gesture);
            }
     }
```

Hope you can help me..

Comment: What error it's showing?

Comment: when I'm adding the gestures, the error is: {"This API has returned an exception from an HRESULT: 0x80070490"}

Comment: have you checked it https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/958044 ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to answer this with the information provided, however, I do see an error in your Post-build event command line. You are explicitly specifying a platform - x64 - and your project your be building under x86 or Win32 configuration, so this will cause a dll mismatch and will not work.

Replace your 'x64' value for '$(Platform)' and see if the error persists.

Also, I would check for two files in your build directory -

- Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder.dll
- Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder.xml

These two should be automatically copied when you add a reference to Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder, but just make sure they are there.

In case you have created your own gesture database file, you can try to run your code with the gesture database that comes with the example code and see what happens.

Source: personal experience. I have been working with Gesture recognition on sample and my own code since the Kinect V2 came out.

Answer (score 1):

try to set your .gbd file attribute in vs as following:

copy to output directory:always

create operation:content